# UIScrollView внутри UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, ios7

Как реализовать стандартное поведение ячейки таблицы, если на ячейке есть `UIScrollView` с меню. Может надо как то настроить `UIScrollView`?

Возникают проблемы с "подсветкой" и "выбором" ячейки - при касании ячейка не подсвечивается и не вызывается метод `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` у `TableViewController`-a.

Пробовал решить проблему с помощью `UITapGestureRecognizer` и переопределением методов `touchesBegan, touchesEnded, touchesMoved` у `subView`.

Ячейка выглядит как на картинке:

[image]

Comment: почему вместо UIScrollView не использовать UIView и не двигать его? Тут вроде как больше подойдет. Держать UIScrollView вместе с UITableView не очень хорошая идея, оно может отлавливать тачи, предназначенные для UITableView и отсюда ваши проблемы.

Comment: @iFreeman двигать `UIView` это тоже изобретение велосипеда, сложно будет добиться плавности анимации

Comment: может быть вот эта сессия будет полезной: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=217, особенно Демо с 11-й минуты.

Comment: @iFreeman двигать UIView с помощью UIPanGestureRecognizer - наиболее подходящий и простой способ

Comment: Есть много полезных библиотек вроде https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell